# How Do I "open folder in explorer" in Netbeans PHP

Tags: netbeans

I'm attempting the conversion from Eclipse PDT to Netbeans PHP, and so far I'm really impressed. What would make things perfect is being able to open up a file structure in the standard windows explorer.

Say I want to copy in a data file I've just tweaked in another app, or downloaded from a remote server, I have to navigate manually to the folder structure that I already have open in the IDE.

It's just about the only thing from Eclipse that I miss in Netbeans. Any suggestions how I can reproduce the functionality?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use [**Path Tools**](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/676/path-tools) plugin (you have to download it from the site and install by manually adding it in *downloaded* section in NetBeans plugin menu)

There is also more recent plugin [QuickOpener](https://github.com/dzsessona/QuickOpener-NetBeans) for newer NetBeans versions.

Other nice plugin that offers this functionality is [CoolEditorActions](https://github.com/anchialas/CoolEditorActions), available through update center in `Infrastuture` category.

Comment: Wow thanks. That did exactly what I needed, and the "Shell on path" option is ridiculously useful.

Answer (score 18):

I am using the QuickOpener plugin. It is available directly in the Tool->Plugin menu in NetBeans.

Then I go to Tools->Options->Keymap and add the alternate CTRL+L shorcut to 'Open in the OS file system browser'

Your all set after this!

Comment: If you have just installed Netbeans you will have to use the "Check for Newest" button in the "Available Plugins" tab so that QuickOpener will appear in the list. (based on experience with NB 8.1)

Answer (score 7):

You should use QuickOpener plugin since Netbeans 7.2. Path Tools do not work on it.

Answer (score 6):

**In Netbeans 12**, the plugin is not available. Fortunately, NetBeans already has a default command for it. Open Tools => Options, Keymap. Search for Open in System. Assign Shortcut, for example, `Alt+S`. Click Apply or OK.

If you select a package or a folder then press the shortcut, it will open the folder in explorer.

[image: Screen Shoot]